# How to fix the results of a particle system to a specific frame

Tags: particles

The image below is about 42 frames from the force field effected Newtonian particle system.

I would like to use the status of these 42 frames as the key for Keyed Particles.

However, I don't know how to keep only specific frames of moving Newtonian particles affected by Force Field.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Not too sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to 'capture' particles at a certain frame, this is easily done but the capture process would convert them all to individual meshes in their own right.  i.e. they'd no longer be particles.  Be aware that their rendering would have to be from a mesh object such as a cube.  Once meshed, they could have physical properties. The method is to select the emitter, go to it's properties at right, open the modifier panel.  Press the "Convert" button and the particles will convert to mesh, albeit a lot of them !

Comment: When I converted a particle to a mesh, I could not keep the particle's position completely like the image attached to my question.
Instead, I was able to get a rough position by creating a new volume particle system in the converted mesh.
It is not perfect, but I am satisfied with it and going to next step.

Comment: J. SungHoon, that's curious.   I detected no change when I pressed the Convert button and have done it again, still with no detectable change.  Could it be changing somewhat when converting back to a new particle system?   Should I place my suggestion up as an answer to your initial problem?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference between the two.
The image attached to the question is that the particles emitted from the box mesh were influenced by the Turbulent force field.
But since it's only 42 frames, I can not use this particle's position as a target for keyed particles.
Because I only want to use the position of the particles captured at 42 frames as a target.

Comment: I got an answer from you and tried to convert at 42 frames with the particle render option set to metaball.
Then a new mesh was created with the turbulent force of the existing shape, and a volume particle system of no physics option was created on that mesh to obtain a roughly similar fixed particle location.
I was satisfied because this approximate location was valid for my animation.

Comment: And the next day I made a new attempt.
Previously, I used a metaball, but this time instead, I use an object with only one vertex as the particle render target.
This allows you to capture exactly one frame of the particle being animated.